# Log all forwarded traffic to new server with iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I rerouted all internet traffic from my old Debian 7 server to my new server with

```
DEST_IP=123.123.123.123
for p in 25 110 143 587 993 995 80 443; do
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport $p -j DNAT --to $DEST_IP:$p
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $DEST_IP --dport $p -j MASQUERADE
done
```

Since I want to turn off my old server soon, I want to know which domains still use my old server. How do I log all forwarded packages to detect services that are still using the old server?

I tried

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "PREROUTING:" --log-level 6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "MASQUERADE:" --log-level 6
```

but that only creates some lines in /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/syslog that don't contain the right information. I only get these:

```
Mar  1 16:08:12 eclabs kernel: [788769.999678] PREROUTING:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:e0:4c:5d:d5:66:44:f4:77:0f:ea:f4:08:00 SRC=213.133.113.83 DST=123.123.123.123 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=11348 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=20760 SEQ=1
```

Where 213.133.113.83 is unkknown to me (seems to be my provider)

Comment: you already can detect the service via port and ip.
if you really need domains:
please read http://serverfault.com/questions/685928/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-precise-domain-name-from-ip-address-logged-in-iptabl

and try to understand why iptables is not the right tool to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `-j LOG --log-prefix "iptables log:"`

before your routing rules or at the head of the nat table, your exact setup might vary.

Comment: I don't get the correct lines logged. Have I done something wrong? (i edited my question)

Comment: you might want to give us an example, however based on the edited question you seem to want to know which domains still use your old server, so you can edit those in your DNS.
That is not something you usually do with iptables, but instead via proxy as posted in the other comment.